# Как получить элементы из Shadow DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

На странице истории Google Chrome, все ссылки хранятся в так называемом «Shadow DOM»:

[image: Код из консоли]

Обычные методы доставания этих ссылок с помощью JavaScript - здесь не работают:

<s>`var els = document.querySelectorAll('#shadow-root ...');`</s>

Как достать все ссылки со страницы истории Google Chrome? То есть, как получать элементы из Shadow DOM?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Можно напрямую из DOM используя свойство `shadowRoot`

```
var tmp = document.getElementById('history-app')
          .shadowRoot
          .children[5]
          .children[1]
          .children[0]
          .shadowRoot;
```